# In Excel 2013, how do I create a shortcut to "Open/Computer/Browse"? [for a file]

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel 2013, it now takes 3 or 4 clicks to browse and open a file (File/Open/Computer/Browse). How I do add a shortcut to the top Quick Access Toolbar to take me directly to the "Browse" dialog?

The suggested Open shortcut simply takes you to the open backstage view - I'm hoping to avoid the backstage view altogether.

I can find the equivalent for "Save As", which is to add the shortcut to "Save As Other Formats" (you need to Customize the Quick Access Toolbar and select "All Commands").

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> gets the job done for me.

Comment: Also works great for Office 2016 (365)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/01/24/show-the-file-open-window-in-excel-2013/

I can't believe someone thought making the backstage the default for something as simple as opening a file was a good idea.  Way to complicate an otherwise simple process.

ETA cliffs notes as per comment below:

```
Click the File tab, and then click Options.
Click the Save category, and click "Don't show the Backstage when opening or saving files"
Click OK to save the settings
```

Comment: I have unchecked "Don't show the Backstage when opening or saving files", however when I hit the Open button on the Quick Access Toolbar it still takes me to the backstage. (I don't have other versions of Office installed as mentioned in the article).

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to go to the Open dialog - and <kbd>F12</kbd> to get to the Save As dialog...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'd like to add a shortcut to the top-left Quick Access Toolbar that brings-up the Open File dialog directly. (And CTRL+O only opens the backstage Open view unfortunately). The F12 is quite handy though thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit clunky, but if you want to discard the mouse, you can go for: <kbd>ALT+F</kbd> > <kbd>O</kbd> > <kbd>C</kbd> > <kbd>B</kbd>. As mentioned above <kbd>F12</kbd> is fastest way to "Save as..."

Once you memorize the combo it takes less than a second.

Comment: But it takes longer than a second to wait for the UI to hurky jerky finally get you into the open (or save) dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple:

1. Go into Options
2. Click General
3. Under "Startup Options" uncheck "Show the start screen when the application starts."
4. Click OK.

Answer (score -2):

in the quick access toolbar, at the top left of word/excel/pp, etc, use the arrow drop-down to add the individual shortcut buttons to the toolbar. Then just click the buttons.

Comment: How I do add a shortcut to the top Quick Access Toolbar to take me directly to the "Browse" dialog?